# Data Source Designer Replace String for DevExpress

Tags: sql, replace, devexpress

This is my first crack at the Data Source Designer from DevExpress and I'm having trouble with a simple string replace on my `SELECT` query.

I'm doing something like

```
SELECT REPLACE(tbl.col, 'Remove Me', '') AS col
FROM table_name tbl
```

But with this, I'm getting an error stating that the table could not be found. I don't know but it seems weird because if I take out the `REPLACE` and just have the query like so

```
SELECT tbl.col
FROM table_name tbl
```

This one works. I don't know what's wrong, because on PL/SQL both queries run just fine. On DevExpress though the query containing `REPLACE` has the said error.

#### EDIT

Also, on top of the error about the table `tbl` not being found, another error is thrown at me saying `rpar` expected.

Comment: If you wrap it in a view will it work?

Comment: @Hambone Sorry I don't know what that is. This really is my first time to use the software.

Comment: In other words, do this: `create or replace view table_view as select replace (tbl.col, 'Remove Me', '') as col from table_name tbl` and then in your code you would `select col from table_view`.  Can you try that to see if it works, in the interest of having a datapoint for what might be the issue?